# How can I make c return an expression?

Tags: r, list, concatenation, expression

The documentation for `c` claims that:

> "*The output type is determined from the highest type of the components in the hierarchy NULL < raw < logical < integer < double < complex < character < list < expression.*"

But when I feed it an expression, what I get is quite clearly a list:

```
> c(1,quote(5+2),3)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
5 + 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

> typeof(c(1,quote(5+2),3))
[1] "list"
> is.list(c(1,quote(5+2),3))
[1] TRUE
```

So what input is it supposed to return an expression for? I tried to feed it a function, but that seems to fall under the "*whereas non-vector components (such names and calls) are treated as one-element lists*" rule and therefore gives me a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`quote()` doesn't return an expression, it returns a variety of different types.  In your case it returns something of type `"language"` (which is actually an unevaluated function call).  Use `expression(5+2)` to get an expression, which is language (or other things) wrapped in a specially marked list.

For example,

```
> c(1,expression(5+2),3)
expression(1, 5 + 2, 3)
```